# Return multiple attributes of an element to a list. LINQ to XML

Tags: c#, xml, linq, list, lambda

I have an xml which is similar to the below.

```
<rowset>
<row attribute1="somevalue1" attribute2="somevalue2" attribute3="somevalue3" attribute4="somevalue4"/>
<row attribute1="somevalue1" attribute2="somevalue2" attribute3="somevalue3" attribute4="somevalue4"/>
<row attribute1="somevalue1" attribute2="somevalue2" attribute3="somevalue3" attribute4="somevalue4"/>
<row attribute1="somevalue1" attribute2="somevalue2" attribute3="somevalue3" attribute4="somevalue4"/>
</rowset>
```

What I am looking to do is return a list, whereby each row with be a list item and the attributes will be sub items. The closest I've got is the following statement but I can't get it to return the values which I can see in debug by going to count and view.

```
var skillslist = testmultilist.Descendants("row").Select(a => a.Attributes()).ToList();
```

Any help would be much appreciated.

This is how I did it in the end.

```
var skillslist = testmultilist.Descendants("row").Select(a => a.Attributes().Select(c => c.Value).ToList()).ToList();
```

Which I can pull strings from by using "string derp = testmultilist[6][3]". This gives the fourth somevalue on line seven.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by "can't get it to return the values which I can see in debug by going to count and view."  What happens when you try to iterate through `skillslist` in your code?

Comment: System.Xml.Linq.XElement+<GetAttributes>d_0 is what I get for each list item. By right clicking skillslist, clicking the plus symbol and then clicking results it shows the subitems and values i.e somevalue1, somevalue2 etc.

Comment: Dude my answer does that (which you edited into your question) so now I am confused what else you need?

Comment: Apologies, I did never type over the second ToList from your example the first time round. Marked as correct because it was right the first time;) Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

UPDATE based on your comment

> **"what I was looking for was to be able to do something similar to this "testmultilist[0][2]"** which would return somevalue3 from the
>   first row although I am not sure I am going about it the right way."

Again you were pretty close, except you were selecting `IEnumerable<XAttribute>` instead of `List<string>` of attribute values.

Here's how to do that (commented for anyone who stumbles upon this:

```
    var skillslist = testmultilist.Elements("row")            // Get the Elements
        .Select(e => e.Attributes()                           // Select the attributes per element (returns IEnumerable<XAttribute>)
            .Select(a => a.Value)                             // Working on the attributes, get only the value
            .ToList()                                         // Must be a list here in order to use indexer [] to access items; this creates the innter List<> items
        )                                                     // this completes the selection of each outer "row" item
        .ToList();
```

Testing app:

```
using System;
using System.Linq;
using System.Xml.Linq;

namespace XLinqAttributeGetNames
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            XElement testmultilist = XElement.Parse(@"<rowset>
                <row attribute1=""somevalue1"" attribute2=""somevalue2"" attribute3=""somevalue3"" attribute4=""somevalue4""/>
                <row attribute1=""somevalue1"" attribute2=""somevalue2"" attribute3=""somevalue3"" attribute4=""somevalue4""/>
                <row attribute1=""somevalue1"" attribute2=""somevalue2"" attribute3=""somevalue3"" attribute4=""somevalue4""/>
                <row attribute1=""somevalue1"" attribute2=""somevalue2"" attribute3=""somevalue3"" attribute4=""somevalue4""/>
                </rowset>");

            var skillslist = testmultilist.Elements("row")
                .Select(s => s.Attributes()
                    .Select(a => a.Value)
                    .ToList()
                )
                .ToList();

            for (var i = 0; i < skillslist.Count; i++)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Row " + i);
                for (var j = 0; j < skillslist[i].Count(); j++)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Item " + j + ": " + skillslist[i][j]);
                }
                Console.WriteLine();
            }
            Console.ReadKey();

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Does that `.Attributes()` accept `IEnumerable` and automacitally produce the actual `SelectMany`?

Comment: @AgentFire - .Attributes() is an XLinq extension method, which works on the current IEnumerable<XElement>, and can take a parameter to filter the collection by name. It does indeed flatten (perform SelectMany) and return a single list.

Comment: This gives a list of all the attributes as single list items while what I was looking for was to be able to do something similar to this "testmultilist[0][2]" which would return somevalue3 from the first row although I am not sure I am going about it the right way.

Comment: @user2166892 see my changed/updated answer based on your comment above

Comment: Hi, thanks for the answer but I have it now in one LINQ statement, see above. There are other elements above and below the rowset element, sorry, I should have added that in at the top.